# How SQL Server compares two NCHAR(1) type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, unicode, sqldatatypes

I'm doing some testing with SQL Server's data types. I have the following code:

```
IF CONVERT(NCHAR(1), '啊') > CONVERT(NCHAR(1), '哎')
    SELECT '>';
ELSE
    SELECT '<';

SELECT '<' WHERE CONVERT(NCHAR(1), '啊') < CONVERT(NCHAR(1), '哎');
SELECT '>' WHERE CONVERT(NCHAR(1), '啊') > CONVERT(NCHAR(1), '哎');
```

When executed I got:

[image]

When I change the operator > to < in the `IF` statement and execute again, I got:

[image]

The result seems a little confusing to me. Can anyone help to explain please?

BTW, I'm on SQL Server 2016 SP1.

Comment: Youre missing the N prefix before your string literals

Comment: @MartinSmith, Yes Martin, I know that, I just want to know how will SQL Server deal with this case.

Comment: It will convert everything to ? most likely. Depending on your default code page and if it contains those chars.

Comment: Essentially '啊' is of type varchar, how will SQL Server do the convert from varchar to nchar? Even if it was converted to `?`, it still have some value and not NULL. So why the IF comparison always goes to the ELSE route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code as you've written it, you've left out one possibility: equality of the two values. As it turns out, that's what's happening. Here's a little code:

```
SELECT '=' WHERE CONVERT(NCHAR(1), '啊') = CONVERT(NCHAR(1), '哎');

SELECT UNICODE(CONVERT(NCHAR(1), '啊')), 
   UNICODE(CONVERT(NCHAR(1), '哎')), 
   NCHAR(UNICODE(CONVERT(NCHAR(1), '哎')));
```

The first select shows that the two values do indeed compare as equal, and the second shows why. Specifically, absent the `N` prefix on your string literals, SQL treating them as ASCII is saying "those are out of range for ASCII!" and returning a literal question mark.